# Get the rendered href attribute of a Link

Tags: java, apache, wicket

I am working with Wicket 1.5-M3. I am a newbie. Below is HTML snippet:

```
<a wicket:id="link" href="a">some link</a>
```

I want to get the URL (i.e., href) of the link. How could I get the generated link of a page after rendering? I want to write a test-case that checks if the generated link is same to a predefined link. How could I do it?

Any hint or tutorial/example?????

### Update

Below is Java tester class code and html code:

```
@Test
    public void homepageRendersSuccessfully()
    {
        String ab;
        //start and render the test page
        tester.startPage(HomePage.class);

        //assert rendered page class
        tester.assertRenderedPage(HomePage.class);

        ab = tester.getTagByWicketId("lnk").getAttribute("href");
        System.out.println("Clicked Link is: "+ab);
    }
```

**HTML Markup**

```
<a wicket:id="link">This is a faulty link</a>
```

**Java Code**

```
public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        add(new BookmarkablePageLink("link", RandomPage.class, new PageParameters().set("id", 2L).set("sid", 3L)));

    }
```

Test case does not produce any run-time generate links. Test-case produces following output:

> Clicked Link is:

Answer (score 1):

I think you ask how to do this with WicketTester ?!

If YES then you can use `WicketTester#startPage(Class)` to "render" the page. Then use `org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester#getTagByWicketId("link")` to get a `TagTester` for the `<a>` and finally use `org.apache.wicket.util.tester.TagTester#getAttribute("href")` to get the value of the `href` attribute and assert.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried to follow your instruction. However, it did not work. I updated my question with all the sample code and output. I do not know much about Wicket. I would appreciate if you can provide some code sample. Thanks!

Comment: The component id is "link", and in your test you use "lnk" (missing 'i'!).

Answer (score 0):

Wicket has few different ways of composing links, try to understand following:

- page links are dynamics (depending on the current page, link id, etc.)
- AJAX links are definitely different
- by default page URL is a generic URL, it has no nice name
- page can be mounted to a fixed URL, than it browser is redirected to that URL, not in links by default
- link is a subclass of BookmarkablePageLink class, than a nice URL is in HREF link's attribute as well

**See more details on**

- [BookmarkablePageLink](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/BookmarkablePageLink.html%20api-doc%20for%20BookmarkablePageLink) (api-doc)
- [WebApplication#mountPage(String, Class)](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/WebApplication.html#mountPage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) (api-doc)
- [Mounting Pages](http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-pages/) (book: Wicket in Action)
- [URL's in Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/urls.html) (Wicket Guide)
- [Wicket Examples](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x) (Wicket Library)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my updated question. I am trying to write a test-case to make sure run-time generated links are correct.